# Get filtered List<T> from XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I am using following code to get List from xml file -

```
    public static List<T> GetListFromXml<T>(string filePath)
    {
        using (TextReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
            return (List<T>) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
```

However, I also need a way of filtering records where I can filter list by -
- no. of records to take from xml file
- filter by a particular node value
So signature of above method will change to -

```
    public static List<T> GetListFromXml<T>(string filePath, 
                                            int listCount, 
                                            string filterbyNode, 
                                            string filterByValue);
```

Please guide me if I can filter directly from XML file or I should filter from returned list?

---

P.S.

The xml file mentioned above is also created from code using -

```
    public static void WriteListToXml<T>(List<T> list, string filePath)
    {
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<T>));
            serializer.Serialize(writer, list);
        }
    }
```

Why I am saving my custom collection returned from database to xml file - because I want to process only a batch of records at a time.

and XML file snippet (generated from above code) -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfClassifiedLocation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CLocation>
    <CId>5726</CId>
    <Long>0</Long>
    <Lat>0</Lat>
    <Postcode>ZZ1 5ZZ</Postcode>
    <Street />
    <Town />
  </CLocation>
  <CLocation>
    <CId>5736</CId>
    <Long>0</Long>
    <Lat>0</Lat>
    <Postcode>ZZ1 5ZZ</Postcode>
    <Street />
    <Town />
  </CLocation>
</ArrayOfClassifiedLocation>
```

Comment: Can you use LINQ-TO-XML instead XmlSerializer? Give an example of your XML so I would be able provide you an example based on your XML structure. An example - http://stackoverflow.com/a/8296317/485076

Comment: I've added an example, I believe it would be clear for you since it is very simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below an example of LINQ-to-XML query which consider `cid` paremeter filter. If you put empty string in `cidFilter` the query would return all entries:

```
// you can use Parse() method:
// XDocument loaded = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load("c:\\temp\\testxl.xml");

// return only entry fith CID == 5726
string cidFilter = "5726";
var filteredItems =
loaded.Descendants("CLocation")
    .Select((w, i) =>
            new
                {
                    Index = i,
                    CID = w.Descendants("CId").FirstOrDefault().Value,
                    PostCode = w.Descendants("Postcode").FirstOrDefault().Value
                })
    .Where(item => String.IsNullOrEmpty(cidFilter) || item.CID == cidFilter)
    .ToList();

int itemsCount = filteredItems.Count();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to .net >= 3.5, you should consider using [Linq to Xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx)